Number of atoms is different in xyz file and POSCAR file. Some atom positions of listed in the xyz are missing too in POSCAR. Why?
I am trying to make POSCAR file and xyz file using vasp for NbReSi compound using VESTA. However, I notice that the number of atoms for xyz file is given as 41 whereas for POSCAR is it 36.
Further, I notice that some lines in the xyz file depicting Re atom coordinates (2nd,3rd,4th, 6th, 9th Re atom in xyz file) is missing in the POSCAR file.
Can anyone kind to explain why there is the difference? Can I use the POSCAR file for vasp calculation in the current form? or i get the POSCAR (or xyz) file wrong. Please help.
The POSCAR, xyz and cif files are given here
POSCAR:
1.0
        7.0700001717         0.0000000000         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000        11.4420003891         0.0000000000
        0.0000000000         0.0000000000         6.6059999466
   Re   Nb   Si
   12   12   12
Cartesian
     0.000000000         0.000000000         1.652160499
     3.535000086         0.000000000         1.652160499
     3.535000086         5.721000195         4.955160670
     0.000000000         5.721000195         4.955160670
     0.208565006         4.306768877         0.792719976
     6.861435113         7.135231512         0.792719976
     3.743565145         7.135231512         0.792719976
     3.326435027         4.306768877         0.792719976
     3.743565145        10.027769071         4.095719998
     3.326435027         1.414231318         4.095719998
     0.208565006         1.414231318         4.095719998
     6.861435113        10.027769071         4.095719998
     1.767500043         2.292976819         1.958018454
     5.302500129         9.149023570         1.958018454
     5.302500129         8.013977014         5.261018427
     1.767500043         3.428023375         5.261018427
     1.767500043         8.916750611         1.788244236
     5.302500129         2.525249778         1.788244236
     5.302500129         3.195750416         5.091244013
     1.767500043         8.246249973         5.091244013
     1.767500043        11.417972293         6.062986812
     5.302500129         0.024028096         6.062986812
     5.302500129         5.696972098         2.759986839
     1.767500043         5.745028291         2.759986839
     1.767500043        11.152517482         3.339333096
     5.302500129         0.289482907         3.339333096
     5.302500129         5.431517288         0.036333123
     1.767500043         6.010483101         0.036333123
     0.042420001         1.916535113         6.574951713
     7.027580295         9.525465106         6.574951713
     3.577419962         9.525465106         6.574951713
     3.492579999         1.916535113         6.574951713
     3.577419962         7.637535478         3.271951740
     3.492579999         3.804464911         3.271951740
     0.042420001         3.804464911         3.271951740
     7.027580295         7.637535478         3.271951740

XYZ:
41
Niobium rhenium silicide (1/1/1)
Re    0.000000    0.000000    1.652160
Re    0.000000   11.442000    1.652160
Re    7.070000    0.000000    1.652160
Re    7.070000   11.442000    1.652160
Re    3.535000    0.000000    1.652160
Re    3.535000   11.442000    1.652160
Re    3.535000    5.721000    4.955160
Re    0.000000    5.721000    4.955160
Re    7.070000    5.721000    4.955160
Re    0.208565    4.306769    0.792720
Re    6.861435    7.135232    0.792720
Re    3.743565    7.135232    0.792720
Re    3.326435    4.306769    0.792720
Re    3.743565   10.027769    4.095720
Re    3.326435    1.414231    4.095720
Re    0.208565    1.414231    4.095720
Re    6.861435   10.027769    4.095720
Nb    1.767500    2.292977    1.958018
Nb    5.302500    9.149024    1.958018
Nb    5.302500    8.013977    5.261018
Nb    1.767500    3.428023    5.261018
Nb    1.767500    8.916751    1.788244
Nb    5.302500    2.525250    1.788244
Nb    5.302500    3.195750    5.091244
Nb    1.767500    8.246250    5.091244
Nb    1.767500   11.417972    6.062987
Nb    5.302500    0.024028    6.062987
Nb    5.302500    5.696972    2.759987
Nb    1.767500    5.745028    2.759987
Si    1.767500   11.152517    3.339333
Si    5.302500    0.289483    3.339333
Si    5.302500    5.431517    0.036333
Si    1.767500    6.010483    0.036333
Si    0.042420    1.916535    6.574952
Si    7.027580    9.525465    6.574952
Si    3.577420    9.525465    6.574952
Si    3.492580    1.916535    6.574952
Si    3.577420    7.637535    3.271952
Si    3.492580    3.804465    3.271952
Si    0.042420    3.804465    3.271952
Si    7.027580    7.637535    3.271952

cif file:
#(C) 2023 by FIZ Karlsruhe - Leibniz Institute for Information Infrastructure.  All rights reserved.
data_600059-ICSD
_database_code_ICSD 600059
_audit_creation_date 2013-02-01
_audit_update_record 2019-08-01
_chemical_name_common 'Niobium rhenium silicide (1/1/1)'
_chemical_formula_structural 'Nb Re Si'
_chemical_formula_sum 'Nb1 Re1 Si1'
_chemical_name_structure_type TiFeSi
_exptl_crystal_density_diffrn 11.45
_citation_title

;
Structure and superconductivity studies on ternary equiatomic silicides, MM'Si
;
_publ_section_comment 'Cell and Type only determined'
loop_
_citation_id
_citation_journal_full
_citation_year
_citation_journal_volume
_citation_page_first
_citation_page_last
_citation_journal_id_ASTM
primary 'Bulletin of Materials Science' 1985 7 215 228 BUMSDW
loop_
_citation_author_citation_id
_citation_author_name
primary 'Subba Rao, G.V.'
primary 'Wagner, K.'
primary 'Balakrishnan, Geetha'
primary 'Janaki, J.'
primary 'Paulus, W.'
primary 'Schoellhorn, R.'
primary 'Subramanian, V.S.'
primary 'Poppe, U.'
_cell_length_a 7.070(5)
_cell_length_b 11.442(5)
_cell_length_c 6.606(5)
_cell_angle_alpha 90.
_cell_angle_beta 90.
_cell_angle_gamma 90.
_cell_volume 534.39
_cell_formula_units_Z 12
_space_group_name_H-M_alt 'I m a 2'
_space_group_IT_number 46
loop_
_space_group_symop_id
_space_group_symop_operation_xyz
1 'x+1/2, -y, z'
2 '-x+1/2, y, z'
3 '-x, -y, z'
4 'x, y, z'
5 'x, -y+1/2, z+1/2'
6 '-x, y+1/2, z+1/2'
7 '-x+1/2, -y+1/2, z+1/2'
8 'x+1/2, y+1/2, z+1/2'
loop_
_atom_type_symbol
_atom_type_oxidation_number
Re0+ 0
Nb0+ 0
Si0+ 0
loop_
_atom_site_label
_atom_site_type_symbol
_atom_site_symmetry_multiplicity
_atom_site_Wyckoff_symbol
_atom_site_fract_x
_atom_site_fract_y
_atom_site_fract_z
_atom_site_B_iso_or_equiv
_atom_site_occupancy
Re1 Re0+ 4 a 0 0 0.2501 . 1.
Re2 Re0+ 8 c 0.0295 0.3764 0.12 . 1.
Nb1 Nb0+ 4 b 0.25 0.2004 0.2964 . 1.
Nb2 Nb0+ 4 b 0.25 0.7793 0.2707 . 1.
Nb3 Nb0+ 4 b 0.25 0.9979 0.9178 . 1.
Si1 Si0+ 4 b 0.25 0.9747 0.5055 . 1.
Si2 Si0+ 8 c 0.006 0.1675 0.9953 . 1.
#End of TTdata_600059-ICSD ```


please format the cif file in code segements to it is readable :) surround code in triple backticks ```

I have edited the cif as you have recommended.

According to your .cif file the structure has 36 atoms. However, some of atoms are located at the cell edges (one of the coordinates is about zero). So, in .xyz file these atoms are duplicated at both cell edges. You can check it if you compare .vasp and .xyz files: one Re atom at (0.000000 0.000000 1.652161) in .vasp but two atoms in .xyz: (0.000000 0.000000 1.652161) and (0.000000 11.442000 1.652161) which are the same.

I have edited my question for clarity. can you help.
